# Asp.net MVC 5 View not rendering until page reloaded with F5

Tags: javascript, c#, jquery, asp.net-mvc-5, signalr

When a user of my application presses the "Log Out" button directly, they are logged out and returned to the login page (see code below for both actions). This is working as intended, however admin users have the ability to force log out individual users. I'm currently accomplishing this with SignalR, and have run into a strange issue.

When I redirect to `LogOff` from the client method, everything is called properly. The client user is logged off, and the `RedirectToAction` properly redirects to the `LogIn` action. However, the `LogIn` view doesn't render until I manually refresh the page with F5. I've been completely unable to figure out why the view isn't rendering the first time

**Log Off Action**

```
    public ActionResult LogOff()
    {
        FormsAuthentication.SignOut();

        return RedirectToAction("Login", "Account");
    }
```

**Log In Action**

```
    public ActionResult Login(string returnUrl, string displayMsg)
    {
        ViewBag.ReturnUrl = returnUrl;
        ViewBag.DisplayMsg = displayMsg;
        ViewBag.PasswordAttempts = 0;
        return View();
    }
```

**SignalR Client Method**

```
$.connection.hub.start();
authHub.client.LogOut = function () {
    $.ajax({
        url: '@Url.Action("LogOff", "Account", new { area = ""})',
        type: "POST"
    });
    $.connection.hub.stop();
}
```

**Log In View**

```
section id="loginForm">

            <div class="col-md-12">
                <div class="wrap">
                    <p class="form-title">Log In</p>

                        @using (Html.BeginForm("Login","Account",new {ViewBag.ReturnUrl, ViewBag.PasswordAttempts}, FormMethod.Post, new{@class="login"}))
                        {
                            @Html.AntiForgeryToken()
                            <section class="DisplayMsg">@ViewBag.DisplayMsg</section>

                            <section>@Html.ValidationMessageFor(m => m.UserName) </section>
                            <label>User Name:</label> @Html.TextBoxFor(m => m.UserName)

                            <section>@Html.ValidationMessageFor(m => m.Password)</section>
                            <label>Password:</label>@Html.PasswordFor(m => m.Password)

                            <input type="submit" value="Log In" class="btn btn-success btn-sm" />
                                @*<div class="reset-forgot">
                                    <div class="row">
                                        <div class="col-md-6 reset-pass-content">
                                            @Html.ActionLink("Reset Password", "PasswordReset", "Account", new {area = string.Empty})
                                        </div>
                                    </div>
                                </div>*@
                        }
                </div>
            </div>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Because you do an Ajax call, that will never redirect the user to login page, it will just signout the user in server side. you can use `location.href` to redirect the user to login page after being signout in the server :

```
$.connection.hub.start();
   authHub.client.LogOut = function () {
      $.connection.hub.stop();
      $.ajax({
      url: '@Url.Action("LogOff", "Account", new { area = ""})',
      type: "POST",
      success: function(){
          location.href = '@Url.Action("Login", "Account")'
      }
  });
}
```